# Radiogroup state after activity change

Tags: android, radio-button

I have two activities with radiogroups.  Using a drop down spinner I can switch between activities.  However I lose the values of my radiobutton selections on activity change.  Is there an easy solution to implement?

Comment: you can use shared preferences to store the data.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

save the data needed in the value..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.putExtra("key","value");
...
startActivity(intent);
```

read in the other activity

```
String data = getStringExtra("key");
```